# Perforce to Git: Invalid option: -r

Tags: git, version-control, migration, perforce, git-p4

I am trying to migrate a project from Perforce into Git. I am using `git-p4` as my main tool to do the heavy lifting for me, and it comes by default with Git on Windows:

`C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-p4`.

Following [**Migrating Perforce to Git in Windows**](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2016/10/27/migrating-perforce-to-git-in-windows/), I have reached the step where I execute my cloning command: `git p4 clone <PerforceRepo>` (where p4 is an alias for the file git-p4.py)

I keep getting error:

> Invalid option: -r.

```
C:\P4-To-Git>git p4 clone //depot/C:\build\mainline@all .
Importing from //depot/C:/build/mainline@all into .
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/P4-To-Git/.git/
Perforce client error:
        p4 -h for usage.
        Invalid option: -r.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-p4", line 3840, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-p4", line 3834, in main
    if not cmd.run(args):
  File "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-p4", line 3706, in run
    if not P4Sync.run(self, depotPaths):
  File "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-p4", line 3546, in run
    changes = p4ChangesForPaths(self.depotPaths, self.changeRange, self.changes_block_size)
  File "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-p4", line 852, in p4ChangesForPaths
    changeEnd = p4_last_change()
  File "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-p4", line 317, in p4_last_change
    return int(results[0]['change'])
KeyError: 'change'
```

I have looked into p4-git python file and there is no place where `-r` is being used. Any help?

Comment: Your P4 path doesn't seem correct: `//depot/C:\build\mainline@all`. Either use a depot path (like `//depot/foo/bar/mainline/...`) or possibly a local path (`C:\build\mainline\...`), if _git-p4_ supports it. Also, are you sure about the "`@all`"? Is that a label?

Comment: @sferencik my p4 path seems to be valid, since other (your) paths examples did not work + first line of my example displayed the path correct. I am not sure what did you mean? Can you type the whole command? And `@all` is telling git-p4 to import all the history too

Comment: `//depot/foo/bar/mainline/...` is just an example. Naturally, your project doesn't live under "foo/bar". You need to find the actual depot path to your project. Do you use Perforce at all? Or someone on your team who could help you figure out the correct depot path? I strongly doubt `//depot/C:\build\mainline` is correct.

Comment: @sferencik Sorry I am so confused right now, your first comment suggests a _"foo/bar"_ depot path, then your second comments says it won't look like a _"foo/bar"_. Could you help me find my depot path? Show an example of a depot path?

Comment: @SandraK connect to your Perforce server and try running some commands like `p4 depots` and `p4 files //depot/...` and `p4 dirs //depot/*`.  That might give you the general idea of what your depot looks like and suggest which path(s) you want to import.  If you get a connection error when you try to run those commands, this effort is doomed because you do not have a Perforce server that is reachable via the `P4PORT` value set on this machine (which is what git-p4 is going to try to use).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting `git-p4.retries` to 0?

```
if retries > 0:
    # Provide a way to not pass this option by setting git-p4.retries to 0
    real_cmd += ["-r", str(retries)]
```

Or upgrade your `p4` executable so it supports the `-r` global flag -- this option was added in the 2012.2 release:

```
Minor new functionality in 2012.2

    #384638 *** ** *
        The net.maxwait configurable can be used to specify a hard limit
        (in seconds) on the maximum time that a connection will wait for
        any single network send or receive to complete. The 'p4 sync'
        command now supports a '-r' global flag to specify that the sync
        command should be retried if a network error occurs.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how do I set `git-p4.retries`? I tried opening the file and hardcoding it but that did not work

Comment: Not positive (I'm a complete git novice, just searching docs here) but I think you want `git config`?  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config  Or if that doesn't work just get a new `p4` executable, it's a free download (ftp.perforce.com) and all you have to do is replace the old one with the new one.

Comment: Did you figure out how to set git-p4.retries?