# Perforce to Git: Clone error "No changes have been made"

Tags: git, version-control, migration, perforce, git-p4

I am trying to migrate a project from Perforce into Git. I am following and on the cloning step, the execution stops and a message is displayed:

> No changes to import!
>
> Not checking out any branch, use "git checkout -q -b master "

What could be the issue?

```
C:\Test-Git>git p4 clone //depot/C:\build\mainline@all C:\Test-Git
Importing from //depot/C:/build/mainline@all into C:\Test-Git
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Test-Git/.git/
No changes to import!
Not checking out any branch, use "git checkout -q -b master <branch>"
```

Comment: Your P4 path doesn't seem correct: `//depot/C:\build\mainline@all`. Please see the discussion in https://stackoverflow.com/q/49263004/1540600.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`//depot/C:\build\mainline@all` is not a valid Perforce depot path, so it makes sense that there would be no changes under it to import.  Try supplying the depot path for the Perforce files that you are trying to import.

If you're not sure, try:

```
git p4 clone //depot/... C:\Test-Git
```

Comment: I am sorry, this is a little confusing. Can you show an example of a dept path? Where would it be or/and how would I locate and find my depot path?

Comment: `//depot/...` is a depot path -- try that one.  A really short explanation is that a depot path in Perforce is what a URL is to a web server -- it identifies files in the depot, and it's a very basic and fundamental part of how you interact with Perforce.  If you type `http://www.google.com/C:\build\mainline` into your browser you will not get anything because that's not a valid URL -- same deal!

Comment: Awesome, `p4 depots` showed everything I needed :) thanks a lot ! Do you know if I can put many depots into one git repo?

Comment: What if you pass the path `//...`?  That's how you specify "all depot files" in Perforce.